# Django error: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

I am very new to django so this is probably a noob question.
I am trying to reuse django admin's change list view. I've created a admin model and want to provide the changelist template a list of these objects. In my view I have:

```
def placements(request):
    partner_id = request.session.get('partner_id', 0)
    self = PlacementAdmin(request.GET, Placement.objects.filter(partner=partner_id))
    return render_to_response('publisher/placement/change_list.html', {'cl': self})
```

I get this error when I try to hit this function from a browser:
    'QueryDict' object has no attribute '_meta'
Could anyone tell me what the error is or provide an easier way to accomplish this in case I am on the wrong track completely.

Heres the complete trace:

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8080/publisher/
Django Version:     1.3 beta 1
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'QueryDict' object has no attribute '_meta'

Exception Location:     /Users/imran/django_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py in __init__, line 278
Python Executable:  /Users/imran/django_env/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.1
Python Path:    

['.',
 '.',
 '/Users/imran/Workspaces/publisher/django/pub_admin',
 '/Users/imran/django_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg',
 '/Users/imran/django_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-0.8.1-py2.6.egg',
 '/Users/imran/django_env/lib/python26.zip',
 '/Users/imran/django_env/lib/python2.6',
 '/Users/imran/django_env/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/imran/django_env/lib/python2.6/plat-mac',
 '/Users/imran/django_env/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/imran/django_env/Extras/lib/python',
 '/Users/imran/django_env/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/Users/imran/django_env/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/Users/imran/django_env/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/imran/django_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages']
```

Answer (score 2):

It's best to post the traceback error when posting a question!

That said, the error comes from you passing `request.GET` to a `ModelAdmin` admin object which isn't expecting it.

You have a long road of troubles ahead of you though, as you're trying to use the magical change_list view template which is operated on by a collection of even more magical, undocumented template tags, which just doesn't normally appear in the same sentence as **new to django**.

I think you're on the wrong track simply because django's admin is not easy to hack into.

At a minimum, you'd have to pass in your template a `ChangeList` object for the `cl` variable.

If you really want to do this, the only advice I can give is to take a look at `django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.changelist_view()` since that's what you're trying to replicate.

Seriously though I'd like to talk you out of this. Django's actually really fun to work with!

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'll take a look at ModelAdmin.changelist_view(). But I really like the inline editing, sorting, pagination that comes out of the box in the admin app. It would be really awesome if I could get the same view in my app without doing it all from scratch.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely nice :) So if you're gonna do it, first step is to reproduce the ChangeList object & provide it its required data. Just had to warn you!